# Comment décide-t-on quel mot est l'antécédent d'un pronom relatif?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

Prenons un exemple :

> Jean a acheté un appartement au rez-de-chaussée qui est sombre.

Dans cette phrase, quel est l'antécédent de ce « qui » ? « Appartement » ou « rez-de-chaussée » ? Et pourquoi ?

Merci de m'expliquer avec les règles générales comment déterminer l'antécédent du pronom.

Comment: The problem is the same in English, but at least in French (as the answers make clear) there is the possibility of clarification if the two candidate antecedents are of different genders.

Comment: @HarryAudus In fact, in literary English one has the possibility of referring to the antecedent (without an article) after the word "which". See, for example, any of the works of Dickens.

Comment: "... which former is ..." and "... which latter is ..."?

Answer (score 3):

Le lecteur comprendra que c'est l'appartement qui est sombre : car on s'intéresse en général plus à la luminosité d'un appartement où l'on vit qu'à celle des parties communes de l'immeuble (qui sont rarement bien éclairées, d'ailleurs).

Sur le plan grammatical, toutefois, la phrase est ambiguë. La proposition relative peut avoir pour antécédent aussi bien l'appartement que le rez-de-chaussée.

La phrase serait un peu moins ambiguë si une virgule suivait « rez-de-chaussée » (ou si le locuteur, à l'oral, faisait une pause après ce mot), car la séparation ainsi créée laisserait entendre que la proposition relative n'a pas pour antécédent le mot situé juste auparavant. Il n'y aurait toutefois pas de certitude, même dans ce cas-là.

En conclusion, cette phrase est obscure et donc mal écrite. Il vaudrait mieux écrire par exemple :

> Jean a acheté un appartement sombre au rez-de-chaussée.

Comment: Dans ce cas précis on peut considérer la phrase mal écrite et la réécrire pour lever toute ambiguïté, mais la question reste valide pour d'autres cas : "Ce soir je dîne avec une amie de ma soeur, qui est en vacances.". Virgule ou pas il est difficile de réécrire "mieux" la phrase tout en étant absolument pas ambigu.

Answer (score 1):

No natif speaker. According to H. Ferrar's [[A French Reference Grammar, Oxford University Press]](https://academic.oup.com/fs/article-abstract/66/3/440/643060?redirectedFrom=fulltext) (p. 231), **lequel** is used in the **Nominative**, in written language only, in order to avoid ambiguity, where the normal use of **qui** would leave some doubt as to which antecedent was referred to. E.g.

> La poignée du couteau, **laquelle** était en ivoire.

Here **laquelle**, being feminine, must refer to poignée.

If both antecedents are of the same gender and number, **lequel** is considered to refer to the **former** one.

> Une amie de sa sœur, **laquelle** venait parfois le dimanche. (i.e. une amie)

In your case:

> Jean a acheté un appartement au rez-de-chaussée **lequel** est sombre. (i.e. un appartement)

French version follows below:

---

Non locuteur natif. Selon l'ouvrage [A French Reference Grammar, Oxford University Press](https://academic.oup.com/fs/article-abstract/66/3/440/643060?redirectedFrom=fulltext) (p. 231) de H. Ferrar, **lequel** est utilisé dans le **Nominatif**, en langue écrite uniquement, afin d'éviter toute ambiguïté, lorsque l'utilisation normale de **qui** laisserait planer un doute sur l'antécédent auquel il est fait référence.

> La poignée du couteau, **laquelle** était en ivoire.

Ici, **laquelle**, étant féminin, doit faire référence à la poignée.

Si les deux antécédents sont du même sexe et du même nombre, le pronom relatif **laquelle** est considéré comme se référant au premier nom.

> Une amie de sa sœur, **laquelle** venait parfois le dimanche. (i.e. une amie)

Dans votre cas :

> Jean a acheté un appartement au rez-de-chaussée **lequel** est sombre. (i.e. un appartement)

Comment: C'est assez surprenant : je suis locuteur natif et instinctivement je comprends *lequel* et *laquelle* comme faisant référence à l'antécédent compatible le plus proche !

Comment: @Epvok moi aussi, mais je dois bien avouer qu'en dehors de "ceci/cela" je ne me rappelle pas avoir appris d'autre règle similaire (par exemple : "qui" pour le plus proche,"lequel/laquelle" pour le plus éloigné...)